# pypyodbc connection to sql server

Tags: python, sql-server

Trying to connect to sql server with pypyodbc, but I keep getting the "data source name not found and no default driver specified" error. See below attempt. I'm fairly new to all this, but still thought at least testing a connection would be easier.

```
import pypyodbc

connection = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER = {SQL Server}; Server = servername;Trusted_Connection = Yes")
connection.close()
```

Comment: @Andy lowercase didn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string is missing the `Database` specifier and you should remove the spaces from the `DRIVER` specifier.

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server}; Server = servername;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection = Yes")
```

Comment: Check with removing spaces from the `DRIVER` specifer like this: `DRIVER={SQL Server}`.

Comment: Just make sure you're careful with the driver you're using.  I had issues with NULLS and datetimes when using the FreeTDS unixODBC driver.  Make sure you grab the sql native client drivers to avoid the issues I've had.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
import pypyodbc
conn = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='servername', database='dbname', uid='userName', pwd='Password')
```

Change the servername and other values with your credentials.
It Works perfectly for me.
If you are using an azure sql server, make sure you add your IP to the firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make python connection with SQL Server then you my use MySQLdb module available for python 2.7 as well.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
connectString=Server={SQL Server};Database={Database Name};UID={UserId};PWD={password}
conn = mdb.connect(connectString)
```

alternatively you can use pyodbc.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={SQL Server};DATABASE={Database Name};UID={UserId};PWD={password}
```